# listView selected items to textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listview

So I Got my list view filled with items. When I Select the item it works fine for the first row but then the next row will show the next row.

So it would be like Column 1-4  c1,c2,c3,c4

textbox1 shows on first line value in Row 1 = c1
textbox1 shows on second line value in Row 2 = c2

When I need it to stay in c1

Edit:
So I wanna be able to go to a Job File by reading the properties in Each Row[See Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V9C4.jpg). But the problem is the job file has a properties folder so I will take the values I get from each row to navigate to the correct folder I require if that makes sense. But In the photo that is how its supposed to work but if I select the row under that one it will give me an error because an int does not exist. Because each row after the next will wanna put the value in the column next to it in the wrong textbox.

Error: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.'

```
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        int Itemindex = e.ItemIndex;
        ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[Itemindex];
        //fill the text boxes
        textBox2.Text = item.Text;
       textBox3.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
        textBox4.Text = item.SubItems[2].Text;
       textBox5.Text = item.SubItems[3].Text;

    }

private void Chad2017()
    {
        try
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != "arc1")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "arc1";
                listView1.Visible = true;


                listView1.Sort();
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\1-January");
                string[] dirs1 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\2-February");
                string[] dirs2 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\3-March");
                string[] dirs3 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\4-April");
                string[] dirs4 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\5-May");
                string[] dirs5 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\6-June");
                string[] dirs6 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\7-July");
                string[] dirs7 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\8-August");
                string[] dirs8 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\9-September");
                string[] dirs9 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\10-October");
                string[] dirs10 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\11-November");
                string[] dirs11 = Directory.GetDirectories(JobArc1 + @"\2017\12-December");
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(JobLoc1);
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir1 in dirs1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir1 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir1 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir1 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir1 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir1 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }

                for each (string dir2 in dirs2)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir2 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir2 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir2 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir2 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir2 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir3 in dirs3)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir3 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir3 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir3 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir3 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir3 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir4 in dirs4)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir4 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir4 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir4 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir4 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir4 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir5 in dirs5)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir5 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir5 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir5 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir5 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir5 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir6 in dirs6)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir6 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir6 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir6 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir6 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir6 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir7 in dirs7)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir7 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir7 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir7 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir7 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir7 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }


                }
                foreach (string dir8 in dirs8)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir8 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir8 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir8 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir8 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir8 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir9 in dirs9)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir9 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir9 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir9 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir9 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir9 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir10 in dirs10)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir10 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir10 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir10 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir10 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir10 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
                foreach (string dir11 in dirs11)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir11 + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir11 + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir11 + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir11 + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir11 + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (Contact != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "arc0";
                listView1.Visible = false;
            }

        }
        catch { }
    }
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            if (textBox1.Text != "1")
            {
                textBox1.Text = "1";
                listView1.Visible = true;
                listView1.Items.Clear();

                listView1.Sort();
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(JobLoc1);
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(JobLoc1);
                foreach (string dir in dirs)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string JobNumber = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\thisJobNumber.txt");
                        string JobName = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt");
                        string BidDate = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\BidDate.txt");
                        string Location = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\Location.txt");
                        string Contact = File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\Contact.txt");
                        string[] JobInfo = { JobName, BidDate, Location, Contact };

                        ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem();

                        if (JobNumber != "")
                        {
                            listView1.Items.Add(JobNumber).SubItems.AddRange(JobInfo);
                            //  listView1.Items[].SubItems.Add(File.ReadAllText(@dir + "\\Properties\\JobName.txt"));
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }
                }
            }

            else
            {
                textBox1.Text = "0";
                listView1.Visible = false;
            }
```

Comment: Not clear enough.  What error are you getting?  Post the entire code block from which event is running.

Comment: Now you added too much code.  Which line throws the error?  Never use empty try-catches.  Use the debugger to inspect your object.  You still didn't show *where* you are using that first code block.

Comment: LarsTech i updated showing what line theres the error

Comment: What's the value of e.ItemIndex when the error is thrown?  Use the debugger to inspect the item variable, too.

Comment: Its anything past 0 But its because it does not exist if you look at the photo. This is what happends. You see the first text box on the left thats the current value now say if i go down one and there is no error it will show the data in the next column.

Comment: That picture doesn't help at all since everything looks normal there.  Remove those Try-Catches and run your code.  Do you know how to use the debugger?

Comment: textBox2.Text = listView1.Items[Itemindex].SubItems[Itemindex].Text; This will simplfy things this is what happends Except for only one text box. try it yourself have a text box and listview and multiple item lines and then you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectedItems is a different collection than the Items collection.

Change this:

```
int Itemindex = e.ItemIndex;
ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[Itemindex];
```

to this:

```
int Itemindex = e.ItemIndex;
ListViewItem item = listView1.Items[Itemindex];
```

Comment: Thank you sorry for being so complicated.